# Pandas column select rows regex numbers after a specific word

Tags: regex, pandas

I am trying to extract "Purchase Id: XXXXXXXX" for the following rows in a pandas dataframe but I am not sure of the correct regex expression to select starts with Purchase Id and ends after the digits.

What I have now:

| Description |
| --- |
| "Online order Purchase Id: 14527903 Charge Id: 11111111" |
| "Online order Purchase Id: 90762134 Charge Id: 33345872" |

The desired result:

| Description |
| --- |
| Purchase Id: 14527903 |
| Purchase Id: 90762134 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to match any number of digits after `Product Id:` :

```
df['Description'].str.extract('(Purchase Id: \d+)')
```

or this to match 8 characters after `Product Id:` :

```
df['Description'].str.extract('(Purchase Id: .{8})')
```

Output:

```
                       0
0  Purchase Id: 14527903
1  Purchase Id: 90762134
```